# Revival Badge not Awarded

Tags: support, badges, revival-badge

I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18716858/1288198) on stackoverflow. I have answered this question after about 60 days and got 2 up-votes. I am not sure why I didn't get Revival Badge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more

You did not answer after 60 days, you answered on the same day. The time of *answering* needs to be 30 days after the question was asked.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to be the first to answer. You just need to be the first to reach a score of 2, and the rules regarding that are very awkward. The problem here is the OP is confused. *asked Sep 10 at 10:41* - *answered Sep 10 at 10:46* -- I'm not sure where he got 60 days from. That's not even 1 day.

Comment: @animuson huh, didn't notice that. Fixed.

Comment: @animuson He's getting 60 days since it's been 55 days since he posted; as Manishearth pointed out, it's probably not knowing that the answer needs to be *posted* 30 days later, and that it's not given to just any post once it has 2 up votes and is 30 days old.

Comment: Got it. I think 30 means difference between two of my answers.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal The revival here is the _question_ being revived with a new (and decent) answer, not _you_. :)